# dart:js in the server (handling nodejs package in Dart server)

Tags: dart

We need to interact with MSSQL data base, and could not find a proper package at pub.dartlang.org, we used ti use [SEQUELIZEJS](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) nodejs package before.

I understood the dart:js is for client side only, is there an equivalent way so I can run nodejs package as DART pub! ory work around solution to avoid coding what we need in pure nodejs.

Comment: You could try https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/odbc instead.

Comment: i checked it, it is not that cool in real :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to interact with JavaScript like this on the server.
A workaround would be a service in a language where you have proper MSSQL support and your Dart server app communicates with this service using a network connection to pass queries and results.